# Using Azure DevOps REST Api how can I get the commit hash of a branch?

Tags: git, rest, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

So far I came up with the following URL (on-premises TFS):

```
http://{TFS Server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Team Project}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo Name}/refs?filter=heads&api-version=4.1
```

But it returns all the branches. How can I get just what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this API:

```
http://{TFS Server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Team Project}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo Name}/stats/branches/{Branch Name}?api-version=4.1
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "commit": {
    "commitId": "87fbec24ec18e2d48ef978f0cxxxxxxxxxx",
    "author": {
      "name": "Shayki Abramczyk",
      "email": "shayki5@gmail.com",
      "date": "2019-01-15T18:35:36Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Shayki Abramczyk",
      "email": "shayki@gmail.com",
      "date": "2019-01-01T18:35:36Z"
    },
    "comment": "Added Code",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/shaykia/xxxxxxxx/_apis/git/repositories/815cc0c7-5f3e-404bxxxxxxxx/commits/xxxxxxxx8ef978f0cf356646d089fee7"
  },
  "name": "FeatureBranch",
  "aheadCount": 2,
  "behindCount": 0,
  "isBaseVersion": false
}
```

Comment: That works, only you have a small typo. It should be `?api-version=4.1` instead of `&api-version=4.1`